# Local variable passed in parameters changes in the function despite not being a return value

Tags: vba, function, scope

The `strCont` variable is sent in my function to fill a doc, and I then test that variable instead of having the same content as before being sent (empty string in that case) it has now the value that the `Cont` variable took in the function (`"_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"`).

`strCont` changes value at the exact instant `Cont` does, which means it's not about the Return, but that the two variables are somehow linked together.
Why are those two variables linked  ? Everything I know about functions tells me it should exactly *not* work like that.

Thanks in advance

Here's the code :

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click()
    Dim strClient2 As String, strTag As String, strCont As String
    '...
    strCont = strClient2
    strTag = "client2"
    Call Filling(strCont, strTag)
    If strCont = "" Then Call Filling("", "and2")
    '...
End Sub
```

The function

```
Function Filling(Cont As String, whatev As String)
    'other ifs...
    If Cont = "" Then Cont = "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"
    'fills doc...
End Function
```

Of course, the problem can be (and is in my program) avoided by just passing a copy of the variable in parameters, but this happening is not how it's supposed to, and I just don't understand why.

Comment: You're calling the function, but not doing anything with the output?

Comment: By default, parameters are passed by reference, meaning that strCont and Cont point to the same memory location.  So it is working as expected.

Comment: @Olly I call the function so it fills a word doc, I don't need any variable as output from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While we think of strings as "simple", they actually aren't, "under the covers". In reality, they're "reference types" - you've set the two "pointers" for the strings to the same address in memory, making them completely equivalent. (This won't happen with numbers.) Strings are passed implicitly "ByRef", meaning they can be changed in the other procedure.

Change the function to get the strings explicitly `ByVal`. This way, what's coming into the function will only be changed *in the function*.

```
Sub btnPrint_Click()
    Dim strClient2 As String, strTag As String, strCont As String
    '...
    strCont = strClient2
    strTag = "client2"
    Call Filling(strCont, strTag)
    If strCont = "" Then Call Filling("", "and2")
    '...
End Sub

Function Filling(ByVal Cont As String, ByVal whatev As String)
    'other ifs...
    If Cont = "" Then Cont = "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"
    'fills doc...
End Function
```

Useful links:

- [Passing Arguments by Value and by Reference (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference)
- [Value Types and Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types)
- [ByVal or ByRef – what’s the difference?](http://excelmatters.com/2016/03/10/byval-or-byref-whats-the-difference/)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know pointers worked that way in VBAfunctions.  
Maybe it's just because I'm more used to C#, but VBA way of handling that is kinda weird right ?

Comment: @bookmanB. VBA is pretty much like any VB langauge in this respect, including VB.NET. But, yes, as I recall C#'s default is to pass arguments by value, so it will seem backwards to you :-) It's all in what you're used to... I added some links with more in-depth explanation. But whether C# or VB or any other language: strings are complex types and an address to the memory is stored in the variable (on the Stack, as I recall) as opposed to the value of a numerical type being stored in the variable, itself (on the Heap, if memory serves).